# Refinement of "every finite dimensional normed vector space is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

My textbook states that: "every finite-dimensional normed vector space is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$".

Is this statement strictly true? The set $\mathbb{Q}^n$ has dimension $n$, and can be turned into a normed vector space over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. Yet, it is obviously not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does this theorem need to specify that the vector spaces need to be over a common field? In this case $\mathbb{R}$?

Moreover, is the isometry part true? It seems to me that you could change norms and break the existence of an isometry.

Comment: Uhm... What norm is there on $\Bbb R^n$? Because this looks quite false to me (even, of course, assuming $\Bbb R$-vector spaces).

Comment: What textbook is this? The statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that for this statement the author assumes the vector spaces to be over $\Bbb R$ (and not even, for instance, over $\Bbb C$). It is certainly possible to make a normed-space-like notion for vector spaces over some field $k\ne \Bbb R,\Bbb C$, but it is uncommon at best. For instance, I would assume that, for an ordered field $(\Bbb F,\le)$, a field $k$ and a multiplicative, subadditive and non-negative map $\lvert \bullet\rvert:k\to \Bbb F$ such that $\lvert x\rvert=0$ if and only if $x=0$, it should be possible to define a concept of "norm" on $k$-vector spaces, and consequently a topology. Such topology should not be metrizable in general.

It should be pointed out that the statement itself is quite imprecise. For one thing, in order to claim a vector space to be linearly isometric to $\Bbb R^n$, one should specify a norm on $\Bbb R^n$. However, once a norm has been specified, the statement becomes false, because, for all $n\ge2$, it is quite easy to devise non-isometric norms on $\Bbb R^n$: for instance $\lVert x\rVert_\infty=\sup\{\lvert x_i\rvert\,:\, 1\le i\le n\}$ and $\lVert x\rVert_2=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^2}$ are not linearly isometric for any $n\ge2$, because the closed $2$-balls are strictly convex and the closed $\infty$-balls aren't.

What *is* true is that every normed $\Bbb R$-vector space $V$ of finite dimension is linearly homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{\dim V}$ (as the topology of $(\Bbb R^n,\lVert\bullet\rVert)$ is independent of the norm). Equivalently, any two normed $\Bbb R$-vector spaces of the same finite dimension are isomorphic by a bi-Lipschitz linear isomorphism.

Comment: You say "linearly isomorphic" where you mean to say "linearly isometric".

Comment: @JensRenders Thank you. It was a mix-up with "isometrically isomorphic".

Comment: It may be worth adding that if $(V, \lVert \cdot\rVert_V)$ is a normed vector space and $W$ is a vector space (both over $\Bbb{R}$ say and of same finite dimension), then we can give $W$ a norm such that $(V, \lVert \cdot \rVert_V)$ and $(W, \lVert \cdot \rVert_W)$ are isomoetrically isomorphic. Another true statement is that if $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V)$ and $(W, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_W)$ are inner product spaces over $\Bbb{R}$ of same finite-dimension, then they are isomorphic as inner-product spaces (hence the induced normed vector spaces are isometrically isomorphic).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Perhaps, but then the statement is silly because I could equally say that $\ell^2$ and $\ell^\infty$ are isometrically isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{(\beth_1)}$, provided I put different norms on $\Bbb R^{(\beth_1)}$.

Comment: I'm confused by the use of 'linearly homeomorphic' in this answer. Isn't that the same as an isomorphism in this case? (though not necessarily an isometry)

Comment: @Flintro Reads as: "There is a map which is linear and a homeomorphism".

Comment: Doesn't that mean that there is an isomorphism then? Just not an isometric one right? As any linear homeomorphism would be an isomorphism.

Comment: @Flintro Yes, because it's bijective.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I guess the only error in the original statement is the isometry part then.